# Python 3.8.5 Flask giving internal server error with WSGI application when template is called using render_template in VS Code - 500 server error

Tags: python, flask, web, jinja2

I have been following a YouTube tutorial made by Corey Schafer using Flask. I have reached the 2nd tutorial about using html templates, but that is the only place I have reached. This is the program I am running called hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

app.run()
```

This is the HTML file I have been using, called home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Template Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to run my code, I always get the error     jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template.html. I've tried to look at all possible solutions, but none have seemed to work. How could I fix this? I'm on a Windows 64-bit machine.

Comment: Where is your `home.html` file located? With the default configuration, it should be in a subdirectory called `templates`

Comment: My home.html file is in the templates subdirectory.

Comment: Your error message doesn't seem consistent with the code you have posted. The file seems to be called `home.html` whereas the error talked about `template.html`.

Answer (score 2):

By default un Flask, the template folder is `templates/`. If `home.html` is in the same directory as `app.py`, you need to set `template_folder`.

Here is how to fix your `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

app.run()
```

To use the default template location (which is recommended), this is the file structure you would need to have:

```
app.py
templates
└── home.html
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to paste your code into my editor with the fix, but it's still not working. I'm getting the same error     jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template.html. I also checked my file structure, and it basically matches the same structure you gave.

Comment: I also checked my templating.py application in the Libs, and I found that the '.globals' and '.signals' are unresolved. Could this have caused any issues?

Comment: It looks like your py file mentions `template.html` but you said your file is called `home.html`, you should check if you wrote a different filename in 2 places maybe